# Multiple UITableViews under UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am developing iOS app using Storyboards using iOS 7 with deployment target 5.1.

I have 4 `UITableView`s in one view controller, all have 1/3 width and 100% height of screen. One is always off-screen (they're moving left-right from time to time). I want them to display under `UINavigationBar` provided by `UINavigationController`.

I have set everything up in Storyboard, but XCode formatted only left most table (by formatted I mean that content of `UITableView` starts at the end of `UINavigationBar`. Other tables start displaying content under `UINavigationBar`.

I do not have any code for setting up tables, only `UITableViewControllerDataSource` and `UITableViewControllerDelegate` methods in my view controller.

[image: xcode storyboard]

As you can see in the screen shot, it's not even displaying prototype table cells, because they're under navigation bar.

How to set this right (in Storyboard or programmatically)?

I want content to appear under the navigation bar, but also to start below the bar and go under only when scrolled down.

Comment: could post some screen shots?

Comment: Screenshots should be of the storyboard and the app running. Also, what code do you have (if any) for setting up the views and scrolling them?

Comment: That's what happens in the picture, it also happens with a version before ios7?

Comment: @Ilario No, on iOS < 7 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code in your view controller.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Or put transparent view in table.tableHeaderView. With height of that view equal to height of navigation bars.

Comment: Of course it works, but not the way I wanted it to.
I DO want content to appear under bars, but also to start below bar and only appear under, when scrolled down.

Comment: I checked it inside my application, navigation bars is not transparent, but i can clearly see blurred cells under it.

Comment: Great, putting transparent view on top of first cell work perfectly, though it's nasty workaround. Height of this view should be `64` and one has to remember to set `-64` `ΔHeight` in `iOS 6/7 Details` in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

seen that this problem is only with ios7, I can try to suggest an options:

-first:

[image]

click in storyboard on UIViewController which contains UITableView and as you can see the image I uploaded, uncheck the "under top bars" beside "Extend Edges".

if this does not work, (this is to not make the translucent NavigationBar) try:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int ver_int = [ver intValue];

if (ver_int < 7) {

  }
else {
      self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
  }
}
```

Comment: Same as in @Evgen Bodunov answer, it doesn't solve my problem. I DO want content to appear under bars, but also to start below bar and appear under the bar, only when scrolled down.

Comment: @CrazyYoghurt oh, I did not realize you wanted the navigation bar to be translucent..